# mbr2gpt: Too many MBR partitions found, no room to create EFI system partition

Tags: mbr2gpt

Try to convert MBR to GPT with **[mbr2gpt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt)** introduced with Windows 10 build 1703, it failed with

> mbr2gpt: Too many MBR partitions found, no room to create EFI system partition.

Full log:

```
2017-06-07 22:23:24, Info                         ESP partition size will be 104857600
2017-06-07 22:23:24, Info                         MBR2GPT: Validating layout, disk sector size is: 512 bytes
2017-06-07 22:23:24, Error                        ValidateLayout: Too many MBR partitions found, no room to create EFI system partition.
2017-06-07 22:23:24, Error                        Disk layout validation failed for disk 1
```

Comment: Similar with https://partnersupport.microsoft.com/zh-hans/par_clientsol/forum/par_win/mbr2gpt%E5%A4%B1%E8%B4%A5/1bb05397-134e-490c-94c5-05e4dcbc3e33?auth=1

Answer (score 4):

The mbr2gpt disk conversion tool need three conditions for the validation of disk layout:

- Admin rights (what you already know)
- One of physical disk (or harddrive) with boot partition (MSR) AND os partition
- The validation allows normally one of additional partitions (often it's recovery partition)

If you have more than three partition then check this with diskpart:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart-Version 10.0.15063.0

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: SILERRAS-PC

DISKPART> list disk

  Dist ###  Status          Size    Free     Dyn  GPT
  --------  ------          ------  -------  ---- ---
  Disk 0    Online          117 GB  1024 KB   *    *
  Disk 1    Online          489 GB   455 MB        *
  Disk 2    Online          186 GB      0 B
  Disk 3    Online          931 GB      0 B
  Disk 4    Online          931 GB  1024 KB        *

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Typ               Größe    Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    System             350 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Primary            487 GB   351 MB
  Partition 3    Recovery           452 MB   488 GB

DISKPART>
```

Try to reduce the number of partitions to three partitions.

If you have more than two recovery partitions, then check this out with "ReAgentc /info". This command shows you the current recovery partitions. Often only one of those is active. You can delete the other one with diskpart. Please be careful which partition you delete. The diskpart command is "delete partition override".

I hope my guide is helpful for you.